# any way to edit id tag inside android phone?

Tags: music-player, mp3, mp3-player

any way how to edit (mp3) id tags inside my android? HTC Desire 2.1

I am used to play my music using winamp with right click on directory and select 'play in winamp'. In that case it doesn't matter if you have id tags set up or not. I miss that on Android a lot.

Comment: I see a number of possible apps when I search in the Market for "mp3 tag". Did you try that?

Comment: no I didn't search the Market. I did search here. I like StackExchange very much and want to have all possible questions and answers available for others too.

Comment: I like Stack Exchange too, but questions asking for app recommendations that could be handled with a simple Market search are generally not welcome. If you have some very specific needs and you've struck out with a Market search, then by all means ask. Otherwise, it just seems like a "do my work for me" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this app in the past to edit my tags [AudioTaggerFree](http://www.appbrain.com/app/audiotagger-free/com.ftpcafe.tagger.trial)